# Conceptual question: Does left join with not null filter on the joining key always equal to inner join?

Tags: sql, join, left-join, inner-join

This is a conceptual question. So I dont have any actual code. But it is simple to follow.

Lets stay we have two tables (Join_1 and Join_2) from joining A and B:

Join_1:

```
Select *
From A join B on A.id = B.id
```

Join_2

```
Select *
From A left join B on A.id = B.id
where B.id is not null
```

Question: Does Join_1 always equal to Join_2? You can think of any conditions such  as null values, duplicates and so on.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between Left, Right, Outer and Inner Joins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448023/what-is-the-difference-between-left-right-outer-and-inner-joins)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all practical purposes, "yes".

The only exception would be if `a.id` could be `NULL`.  In that case, the first version would filter out those rows.  The second would include them.

Comment: So under no conditions, Join_1 can have more rows that Join 2?

Comment: Gordon, even if a.id is NULL, wouldn't the 'B.id is not null' filter all rows out of the result set?

Comment: The filter is on B.id. I dont think it would remove null entries on a.id.